# Event listener on a Sencha Touch generated setter

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Is it possible to set an event listener to trigger when a user-defined config property is changed?  Ex.

```
Ext.define('myClass', {
    singleton: true,
    config: {
        myProperty: null
    }
}
```

And I want to set up a listener so that when I call `myClass.setMyProperty('blah');` it gets triggered.  Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated setters does not fire any event.

However you can define your own setter and fire your custom event from it. Your class have to use [`Ext.mixin.Observable`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable) mixin (or extend from some class which use this mixin) if you want to fire events from it.

```
Ext.define('myClass', {
    mixins: ['Ext.mixin.Observable'],
    singleton: true,
    config: {
        myProperty: null
    },
    setMyProperty: function(value) {
       this.myProperty = value;
       this.fireEvent('myPropertySetted');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the recommended way to do it - by overriding the setter?  Or should I be using a different name for my own setter and calling Sencha's `setMyProperty()`?  I.e. what is the value of Sencha's setter if all it's doing is setting `this.myProperty` and not exposing an event?

Comment: With generated setters you can use updaters and appliers. Together with setting property value this is only functionality which they doing. If you want to fire event only if property value is changed, you can also do it from updater, so you do not need to setup your own setter. If you want to now how generated setter exactly looks like you can look at `generateSetter` method in `Ext.Class` http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/source/Class.html#Ext-Class

Answer (score 0):

The comments in the accepted answer actually contain the full answer, so for the sake of googlers who get here, I'll type it up:

The answer is to create a function called applyX or updateX (where X is your capitalized property), depending on if you want to receive the new value before or after (respectively) it is physically changed in the config. Sencha will call your function:

```
Ext.define('myClass', {
    singleton: true,
    config: {
        myProperty: null
    },
    updateMyProperty: function(value) {
        ... do something with value. this.getMyProperty() will also work
    } 
}
```

Read more here:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/core_concepts/class_system.html